# URL routing in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I am having entry in my route.php like - `$route['admin/students'] = 'view_student'`. Here view_student is controller name. Now when from "localhost/school/admin" page I call `<a href="admin/students">Students</a>`, than everything works fine; But when I change my route like - `$route['/school/admin/students'] = 'view_student'`,  and call it from "localhost/school/admin" page as `<a href="/school/admin/students">Students</a>`, than 404 page is shown. Whats wrong in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this code it might help you :**

Here dashboard is the name of controller

```
//this will route as localhost/appFolder/admin/index
  $route['admin'] = 'dashboard'; // for your index page

//this will route as localhost/appFolder/admin/method_name
 $route['admin/(:any)'] = 'dashboard/$1';

//this will route as localhost/appFolder/admin/method_name/param1
$route['admin/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'dashboard/$1/$2';
```

**Link the route Like**

```
// for your index page
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/index'); ?>"></a>

// for your other pages
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/method_name'); ?>"></a>
```

**To link the other controller defined just like**

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('otherControllerName/method_name'); ?>"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You just saved my life. Was stuck in this problem from a week or two. Now it is working perfectly! But I made little modifications in the solution which you just proposed. Kudos to you! Thanks again!

Comment: like a looping statement saved few lines of code too

Answer (score 0):

school is your ci root, so if you define $route['/school/admin/students'], it will seek school class with admin function, that never exist, instead of admin route.

you should read the documentations first before make any step,
 https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: Okay.. That I got it, but the problem persists when I am on "localhost/school/admin/students/by_class" (students is controller class and by_class is its method) page and than want to route to  "localhost/school/admin/register_student" (register_student is controller class) with route as `$route['admin/register_student']`, than it will have url structure "localhost/school/admin/students/admin/register_student" instead of "localhost/school/admin/register_student". How to do such type of route? I mean how can I skip 2 segments in url - here "by_class" & "students".

Comment: If I will make route like `$route['register_student']` than the url structure will be "localhost/school/admin/students/register_student" instead of "localhost/school/admin/register_student". So my question is how to skip this "students" segment from URL?