# First link of pagination shows 404 page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, routes

I am working on pagination of category page. my route is

```
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'public_controller/category/$1';
```

And url to go to category page is `http://localhost/ecom/category/seats` but it shows 404 error page. but when I give `http://localhost/ecom/category/seats/1` it works fine and pagination also works fine second and third links are also working but when I click on 1 in pagination it shoes 404 error page. my controller code is

```
   public function category($cat_slug = null,$offset = null){
 $cat_id = $this->db->where('cat_slug',$cat_slug)->get('categories')->row_array();
 $config['base_url'] = base_url() .'category/'.$cat_slug;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->where('cat_id',$cat_id['cat_id'])->count_all('products');
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
 $data['products'] = $this->public_model->category_page($cat_slug,$config['per_page'],$offset);
 $id['cat_slug'] = $cat_slug;
 $this->load->view('public_temp/header1');
 $this->load->view('public_temp/left1',$id);
 $this->load->view('public/category',$data);
 $this->load->view('public_temp/footer1');
}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Comment: can you suggest any answer to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created a demo for your problem and this is what worked for me ↓↓

```
$route['category']               = 'my_controller/category';       // this route handles all the requests without any additional segments
$route['category/(:any)']        = 'my_controller/category/$1';    // this route handles the requests when only one segment is present
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'my_controller/category/$1/$2'; // this route handles the requests when there are two segments(2nd parameter being a number)
```

This is possible because

> **Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will
>   always take precedence over lower ones.([Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html))**

I also found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292243/url-routing-in-php-codeigniter) you might wanna take a look at. 
Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: now there is problem about products. I am fetching products and its four products every time but on second page or third page products are repeating.

Comment: now there is problem about products. I am fetching products and its four products every time but on second page or third page products are repeating.

Comment: there are only 8 products in one category i.e lights but it's showing four links in pagination and almost two products are repeating on every page

Comment: I honestly don't think that there is anything wrong in the provided code, maybe you're missing something in the logical part. This link might be of help - https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

It shows because your `router expect 2 parameter but you are giving 1 parameter seats`

***Define your route this way***

```
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'public_controller/category/$1/$2';
```

Now call your route `http://localhost/ecom/category/seats/0` for category page
`http://localhost/ecom/category/seats/1` for first pagination

if you want to separate your category route `Define two route one for category page and other for category pagination`

**For category page**

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'public_controller/category/$1';
```

**For category pagination**

```
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'public_controller/category/$1/$2';
```